# Rosjava use Kinect

Tags: kinect, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am playing with rosjava on android and now I want to display data from **kinect** on robot to android. First, I try **RosCameraPreviewView**, but it works with camera on android. Can **RosCameraPreviewView** display data from **kinect** or can I use RosImageView ?
Or I can't use any features from rosjava ?

Thanks for any help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51086/rosjava-use-kinect/) by [LeopoldPodmolík](https://answers.ros.org/users/3844/leopoldpodmol%C3%ADk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The communication is OK, because my android application move with robot. So, it's only about that if any rosjava featured can display data from kinect, or I must implemented ourself ...

---

Originally posted by [LeopoldPodmolík](https://answers.ros.org/users/3844/leopoldpodmol%C3%ADk/) with karma: 66 on 2012-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0